# Sort files into subfolders named by the month within treeview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, treeview

I want sub-folders within folder to be arranged in month wise in treeview control. Treeview control is used to list all the sub-folders within directory. As treeview gets sub-folder according windows explorer but is there any way to sort it in month wise.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, assign your tree view to this datasource

```
        var sortedDirs =
            from dirDate in
                (
                    from dir in Directory.GetDirectories(BASEDIR)
                    select new {
                        Dir = dir,
                        Date = Directory.GetCreationTime(dir)
                    })
            orderby dirDate.Date.Month
            select dirDate.Dir;
```